# What is the difference between building a site on wordpress vs hand coding?

Tags: wordpress

So I'm a beginner to coding and I am wondering what is the difference between building a site using wordpress (which I am not familiar with) as opposed to just hand coding from a text editor like sublime and then hosting it. Should I be using Wordpress? What exactly are the benefits? Thank you.

Comment: SOF is not a programming chat room to invite people to share their ideas or opinions. here you are allowed just to ask exact objective well-formed questions about exact programming situations like errors, coding problems, syntax, design problems, etc. Please find some other place for your kind of question

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you want the website for.

I've both hand coded and used Wordpress (and before that Moveable Type) over the past 15 years.  When I was doing infrequent updates to my website then hand coding was perfect.  I could make it look exactly as I wanted, it had only the elements that I needed and nothing heavy in the backend to slow it all down.

When that all changed to being frequently updated Wordpress was much easier.  The ability to schedule posts was one of the big things that got me into using it.  If you're doing frequent updates, which, say need to post at the same time every day or multiple times in a week, but you're not necessarily available, then it's great.  If you're short on time, then it's also useful because you choose once how you want the site to look then type your information and publish it.  You don't need to amend any code or use FTP.

What you do lack is the personalisation.  Unless you're also going to learn how to make Wordpress themes to properly personalise a Wordpress site, then you're stuck with the templates available for download.  Some are great, some are mediocre and some are very simple.

My next project is to get my sports team online properly, and because there are about five or so people who would need to edit it Wordpress works for this.  I can give people limited access to allow them to post/edit posts but know that because they're restricted, they're not going to break it all, unlike if I allowed them FTP access, which could be a massive disaster with people who aren't familiar with that.

You need to consider what you're really trying to achieve.  If the website is really you and needs to reflect you and you don't update it relentlessly, then hand coding would be my first choice.  If other (perhaps inexperienced) people are involved or you need to do things quickly, then I'd choose Wordpress.

Comment: please don't try to answer such subjective question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your first website, you should use a CMS like WordPress, because it will be easiest for you to publish content online and you will find many free plugins and themes at the wordpress website.
The main difference between a CMS like WordPress and a hand coded website is the first is not create for you. WordPress can be used in many way, but you will have to learn the WordPress codex to create your own themes and plugins. 
With the hand coded, you will create a website optimized for what you need.
But you have to consider, you will have to code again each time you want to edit something, and for some features it will be a lot of work.
WordPress already include many "must have" features like seo friendly URLs, categories and tags etc..
But you can also look for another CMS, smaller than Wordpress

Comment: please don't try to answer such subjective question